# Add slides to collection

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i wanna add to a List(Collection) several slides. 
My code is like that:

```
   Set inhaltsverzeichnis_Slides = New Collection
   Dim inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide As slide
   intNrSlide = CInt(titels.Count / 4)
   slide = 1
   For i = 1 To intNrSlide
    slide = slide + 1
    Set inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(slide, ppLayoutText)
    inhaltsverzeichnis_Slides.Add (inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide)
     Next i
```

But i get a runntimeError 438.  Why can not i add a slide to a collection??
And How can i do that?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that adds all slides of the current presentation to a collection:

```
Dim tmpSlide as Slide
Dim colSlides as New Collection

For Each tmpSlide In Application.Presentations(1).Slides

    colSlides.Add tmpSlide
Next tmpSlide
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line where you add the slide object to the collection to the following (without the parentheses):

```
inhaltsverzeichnis_Slides.Add inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide
```

You cannot use parentheses without a return value - if you really want to use them for some reason, you need to use the `Call` statement:

```
Call inhaltsverzeichnis_Slides.Add(inhaltsverzeichnis_Slide)
```